# Multiple applications having c3p0 configuration gives warning

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

Hi
I have two web application under one tomcat. Both are using hibernate 3.2.1 and c3p0 0.9.1.2. While the second application gets deployed, I always get the following warning message.
Tomcat: **apache-tomcat-6.0.28**

> WARN 2010-11-06 19:04:37,270 A C3P0Registry mbean is already registered. This probably means that an application using c3p0 was undeployed, but not all PooledDataSources were closed prior to undeployment. This may lead to resource leaks over time. Please take care to close all PooledDataSources.

Please help in this regard.

Thanks in advance
Goura

Answer (score 10):

To avoid the `C3P0Registry` from being loaded and registered multiple times (when deploying multiple webapps, when reloading a given webapp), my recommendation would be to move the C3P0 JAR (and the JDBC driver) from the **Webapp** classloader (`WebappX/WEB-INF/lib`) to the **Common** classloader (`$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`).

Answer (score 5):

If you dont want [c3p0 exposed through JMX](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#jmx_configuration_and_management) then you could do:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. where should I add this ManagementCoordinator param?

Comment: In your c3p0.properties or c3p0-config.xml. Don't know how to do it in the hibernate.cfg.xml though.

Comment: I think it's not doable via hibernate. Simply add a c3p0.properties with just the configuration line above.